# Registering an app from one Azure Directory to another Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm able to register a Dynamics 365 app in Azure.  However, when I create the application user in Dynamics, I get this error:[image]

I'm guessing the issue is that my Azure subscription is a different account than my Dynamics account.  How would I be able to add my Dynamics tenant to my Azure subscription?

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to try my solution? And updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your requirement, here is a document about how to [associate or add an Azure subscription to your Azure Active Directory tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory).

But I don't think the issue is related to Azure subscription.

You just need to make sure the tenant you want to register the app in, is the same as the Dynamics tenant. Use your Dynamics tenant account to log into Azure portal to register an Azure AD app. This issue has nothing to do with whether the tenant has an Azure subscription.

But if the Dynamics app requires an Azure subscription for use, you can add the subscription to the Dynamics tenant by following the document above.

Comment: Hi Allen.  Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner.  I wasn't able to switch my directory in Azure because it doesn't exist in my directory list.

Comment: @user1647160 You doesn't need to switch the directory. You should use the Dynamics 365 admin account to log into Azure.

Comment: I created my Dynamics user in Azure AD, used that user to register an app and then added the application id to the application user profile.  That worked.  I think that was what you were referring to.